# What is the central idea of the Bible?

Tags: bible, denomination-survey

I know there are many denominations in the Christian circle. I was wondering if there is a consensus on what the Bible is about? Or in other words is there a consensus in Christianity today on what is the main theme of the Bible.

Luther said of the Bible:

> None of its parts are obscure... The scriptures is the book the more clear in all the world
>   `The Bondage of Will by Martin Luther`

Comment: I cannot find that quote in [The Bondage of the Will](http://www.truecovenanter.com/truelutheran/luther_bow.html). And based on the grammar, I'm guessing it's just a poor translation.  Can you point me specifically to where that quote is taken from?

Comment: [Paul's] letters contain some things that are hard to understand - 2 Peter 3:16.

Comment: @Flimzy sadly the teacher did not provided the specific references

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jesus is the central "idea" of the Bible:

- The old Testament begins with the fall of man and the prophecy of the Redeemer (Jesus)
- The Jewish religion was constantly looking forward to the Messiah (Jesus)
- The New Testament records Jesus' life and public ministry
- The Epistles both explain the doctrine of Jesus as well as re-establish the proofs that the old testament prophecies were fulfilled in Jesus (esp. St. Paul's letter to the Hebrews)
- Revelations/Apocalypse looks forward to the second coming of Jesus

Answer (score 2):

The central thought of the Bible is Christ and the church.

The Old Testament reveals Christ and the New Testament reveals the church as the counter part of Christ (Ephesians 5:32). We cannot simply remain in just knowing Jesus Christ. Our issue of knowing Him must be the edifying, the building up, of the church, which is His body (As revealed in Colossians 1:18). This is God's purpose and desire.

So how can we build up the church? 1 Corinthians 14:26 :)

Much grace, fellow believers in Christ.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading for a class and came across the folowing:

> Augustine proposes that when Christ is viewed has the center of the Bible and love is our supreme good, we understand the Scripture in all their light.
>   `Class notes from pastor René Frey, trough translation from French`